# Mathematical expression for all combination of a 0-1 vector

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a $n\times 1$ vector, $X=[x_1 ,x_2 ,x_3 ,..., x_n]$, whose elements are boolean, i.e., 0 or 1. Is there a concise mathematical expression for $\{\text{all possible outcomes of }\;X\}$? Can it be expressed in the form of coordinate space, such as $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: How about $\{0,1\}^n$?

Comment: Or how about $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestions, are what you suggested formal, rigorous, and well-accepted mathematical expression? I'll use this toward formal research publication so I have to make sure what I use is formal mathematics.

I've found somewhere defined a Boolean algebra B, and then that space can be expressed as B^n, is this a formal way? 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Walkar was right, it is $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$. Thank you!